# Async/Await Expected Behavior

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around async/await syntax

What I can't seem to figure out is why in this code, does "connected" get logged to the console even when there is an error in the connection to mysql.

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
function connection() {
    //return a promise to be consumed in an async function
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdatabase');
        let db = mongoose.connection;
        let sw = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'reporting',
            Promise: Promise,
            database: 'testdatabase'
        });

        //Only resolve if both database connections are made successfully
        sw.then(() => {
            db.on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
            db.once('open', () => {
                resolve(db);
            });
        }).catch((e) => {

            reject(e);
        })
    });
}

//Await connection and return true or false for more synchronous code style
async function connect() {
    let connected = false;
    try {
        //should pause execution until resolved right?
        await connection();
        connected = true;

    } catch (e) {
        //Makes it here successfully
        console.error(e);
        connected = false
    } finally {
        return connected
    } 
}

if (connect()) {
    //This code also gets fired?
    console.log('connected');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `async function`s are still asynchronous, they will not block anything or magically wait before they return. Calling `connect()` always *returns a promise* which is always truthy so "connected" will get logged immediately in every case.

If you want to wait for the connection, you will have to `await` the result and wrap the `if` statement in an `async function` as well:

```
async function connect() {
    try {
        await connection();
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return false
    } 
}

(async function() {
    if (await connect()) {
//      ^^^^^
        console.log('connected');
    }
}());
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that async functions returned promises themselves. I'm not sure how this is much better than the Promise.then paradigm though.

Comment: @richbai90 It's just syntactic sugar that allows the use of control structures without nesting `then` calls. The semantics stay the same, though. See nem035's answer below for how it would look without `await`.

Answer (score 1):

Async functions return promises so this

```
if (connect()) { // <--- connect() will return a promise
  // and a promise always evaluates to a truthy value, 
  // that's why this code always runs
  console.log('connected');
}
```

Could be:

```
connect().then(isConnected => {
  if (isConnected) {
    console.log('connected');
  }
});
```

Or you could await for the promise returned from `connect()` as well, as Bergi [demonstrated in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40137843/3928341).